# DialogFlow integration Cortana ApiAiSDK

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, cortana

I'm trying to implement an integration between DialogFlow and Cortana using : https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/cortana-exporter

But I would like to know if anyone has succeeded because I have considerable difficulty in implementing the C # code of visual studio.
Is the example available correct and integrates correctly?
THK

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive in your use case? Things have changed on the Cortana since 2017.

Comment: For example, you have an app using Cortana VCD you want to hook into DialogFlow for LU? Or you have an action or skill that you'd like to use DialogFlow for?

Comment: Yes Micromuncher.. i've an app created with Visual Studio... but i don't know how to connect with Dialogflow.
Can u help me?

Comment: I create skills for both platforms but I have not tried to call dialogflow from botframework (or call LUIS via webhook).  All I know is its possible to do cross service calls by setting up the appropriate app registrations to the services and knowing their restful apis. Also, you don't *need* to use C# on MS stack (you can use node/js).  I also have not created VCD apps - just skills.  If you can give a lot more detal on your use case, I might have architectural ideas.